# How can I select descendents of each instance of a class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here’s a simplified version of my code.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">

    </div>
    <div class="column">

    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">

    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">

    </div>
    <div class="column">

    </div>
    <div class="column">

    </div>
</div>
```

I’m trying to add the heights of every “column” DIV within each “row” DIV. In other words, I want to add the two “column” DIVs in the first “row” DIV; the one “column” DIV in the second “row” DIV; and the three “column” DIVs in the third “row” DIV. How can I do this?

Comment: you want to calculate total height of all `div with class column` inside `div with class row`, am i rite?

Comment: Yep! I know I'm explaining it terribly but:

1 + 1 in the first DIV;

1 in the second DIV;

1 + 1 + 1 in the third DIV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking...

```js
// Loop through each .row...
$('.row').each(function(i) {
  var totalHeight = 0;

  // Loop though descendant .column's in this .row...
  $(this).find('.column').each(function() {

    // Add .column height to total...
    totalHeight += $(this).height();
  })

  // do something with the total...
  console.log('columns in row ' + i + ' have a total height of ' + totalHeight + 'px');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    Column
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Column
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    Column
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    Column
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Column
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Column
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's it! I couldn't figure out how to loop through the COLUMN divs within each ROW div. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

(click on `run code snippet` to see the working example);

```js
function SetColumnHeightCtrl($) {
  var rows = $('.row');
  
  rows.each(function(index) {
    var height = 0;
    var $row = $(this);
    
    $row.find('.column').each(function() {
      var $column = $(this);
      height += $column.height();
    });
    
    console.log(`${index} row height:`, height);
    $row.css('height', height);
  });

}
jQuery(document).ready(SetColumnHeightCtrl);
```

```css
.row { background: lightseagreen; display: flex; padding: 5px; margin-bottom: 1em; }

.column { background: lightcoral; margin: 0 5px; flex: 1 1 auto; }

.column:nth-child(odd) { height: 30px; }
.column:nth-child(even) { height: 70px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="column"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: He means add (+) not add()

Comment: Yeah, I really didn't explain it well. Sorry! Here's my situation.

I have a number of COLUMN divs inside a number of ROW divs. How can I add up the height of all the COLUMN divs within each ROW div?

For example, in my example above, if we assumed every column had a height of "1", I would get the values [1 + 1 = 2] for the first ROW div; [1 = 1] for the second ROW div; and [1 + 1 + 1 = 3] for the second ROW div.

Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 1):

A simple `$("div.row>div.column")` is enough to select every `div with class column` inside `div with class row` the use `.height()` to compute the current height.

The code :

```
$("div.row>div.column").each(function() {
   sum += ($(this).height());
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  console.log(calc());
});

function calc() {
  var sum = 0;
  $("div.row>div.column").each(function() {
    sum += ($(this).height());
  });
  return sum;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
1
<div class="row">
  a
  <div class="column">
    b
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    c
  </div>
  d
</div>
2
<div class="row">
  e
  <div class="column">
    f
  </div>
  g
</div>
3
<div class="row">
  h
  <div class="column">
    i
  </div>
  j
  <div class="column">
    k
  </div>
  l
  <div class="column">
    m
  </div>
  n
</div>
4
```

Comment: I‘m not 100% sure, but does this give separate sums for each ROW div or just one big sum of all COLUMN divs' height?

Comment: @Andrew Some of all column divs. Do you want sum of columns in each row?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var height = 0;

 $('.row').children('.column').each(function() {
     height += $(this).height();
 });

 console.log(height);
});
```

```css
.column {
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">

    </div>
    <div class="column">

    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">

    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">

    </div>
    <div class="column">

    </div>
    <div class="column">

    </div>
</div>
```

Returns 1800